# How do I see the Reach compiler's intermediate outputs?

Tags: reach

I run my programs with `reach run` and it creates `build/index.main.mjs`, which contains compiled bytecode, but I want to see (for example) the intermediate solidity file that it generates before compiling it all the way into bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reach compile` to perform only the compilation step, and to access compiler-specific options such as the `--intermediate-files` flag, which will dump a bunch of intermediate files including `build/index.main.sol`.

`reach compile --help` has more instructions. Technically the compiler is a program called `reachc` but `reach compile` runs a docker container for you containing the compiler. So you should translate any usage messages saying `reachc` to mean `reach compile`.

See also [the online docs for `reach compile`](https://docs.reach.sh/ref-usage.html#%28part._ref-usage-compile%29).